# JAVA jframe.remove(panel) doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, jpanel

I have a Jframe with two panels and i am trying to change the panels/views using jmenu items.

The first panel adds data to a database. User can then switch to the view panel by clicking the JMenuBarItem.

The Second panel fetches data from the database and displays the results in a JTable.

Everything works fine but when i switch back and forth to the second panel it adds another panel instead of removing it/replacing it. See linked images below to better understand

First Panel

[image: First Panel]

Second Panel

[image: Second Panel]

Second Panel after switching back and forth

[image: Second Panel after switching back and forth]

```
package employeerecords3;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;


public class EmployeeRecords3 extends JFrame {

    JLabel empnolb, empnamelb, empdptlb, basicsallb, hseallowancelb;
    JTextField empnotf, empnametf, empdpttf, basicsaltf, hseallowancetf;
    JButton submitbtn, cancelbtn;
    String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";

    EmployeeRecords3() {
        setTitle("Employee Records");

        final JPanel addpanel = new JPanel();
        final JPanel viewpanel = new JPanel();
        setTitle("Employee Records");

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menubar);
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(file);
        JMenuItem add = new JMenuItem("Add Employee");
        JMenuItem view = new JMenuItem("View Employees");
        file.add(add);
        file.add(view);

        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (viewpanel.isShowing()) {
                    remove(viewpanel);
                    add(addpanel);
                }

                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                java.util.List<String[]> datalist = new ArrayList<>();

                String[] columnNames = {"Emp ID", "Emp Name", "Department", "Basic Pay", "House Allowance", "Payee", "NHIF", "NSSF", "Pension", "NetPay"};
                try {
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM payroll";
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
                    Statement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String[] results = {rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), Double.toString(rs.getDouble(4)), Double.toString(rs.getDouble(5)), Double.toString(rs.getDouble(6)), Double.toString(rs.getDouble(7)), Double.toString(rs.getDouble(8)), Double.toString(rs.getDouble(9)), Double.toString(rs.getDouble(10))};
                        datalist.add(results);
                    }
                    con.close();
                    String[][] data = new String[datalist.size()][];
                    data = datalist.toArray(data);
                    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

                    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
                    viewpanel.add(sp);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (addpanel.isShowing()) {
                    remove(addpanel);
                    add(viewpanel);
                } else if (viewpanel.isShowing()) {
                    remove(viewpanel);
                    add(viewpanel);
                }

                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });

        empnolb = new JLabel("Emp No");
        empnamelb = new JLabel("Name");
        empdptlb = new JLabel("Department");
        basicsallb = new JLabel("Basic Pay");
        hseallowancelb = new JLabel("House Allowance");

        empnotf = new JTextField();
        empnametf = new JTextField();
        empdpttf = new JTextField();
        basicsaltf = new JTextField();
        hseallowancetf = new JTextField();

        submitbtn = new JButton("Submit");
        cancelbtn = new JButton("Cancel");

        Submit submithandler = new Submit();
        submitbtn.addActionListener(submithandler);

        Cancel cancelhandler = new Cancel();
        cancelbtn.addActionListener(cancelhandler);

        addpanel.add(empnolb);
        addpanel.add(empnotf);

        addpanel.add(empnamelb);
        addpanel.add(empnametf);

        addpanel.add(empdptlb);
        addpanel.add(empdpttf);

        addpanel.add(basicsallb);
        addpanel.add(basicsaltf);

        addpanel.add(hseallowancelb);
        addpanel.add(hseallowancetf);

        addpanel.add(submitbtn);
        addpanel.add(cancelbtn);

        addpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));
        viewpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        add(addpanel);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    private class Submit implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String empNo, empName, department;
            double grossPay, basicPay, hseAllowance, payee, nhif, nssf, pension, netPay;

            empNo = empnotf.getText();
            empName = empnametf.getText();
            department = empdpttf.getText();
            basicPay = Double.parseDouble(basicsaltf.getText());
            hseAllowance = Double.parseDouble(hseallowancetf.getText());

            grossPay = basicPay + hseAllowance;
            payee = 0.3 * grossPay;
            if (grossPay > 100000) {
                nhif = 1200;
            } else {
                nhif = 320;
            }
            nssf = 200;
            pension = 0.05 * basicPay;
            netPay = grossPay - (payee - nhif - nssf - pension);

            String query = "INSERT INTO payroll(EmpID,EmpName,Department,BasicPay,HouseAllowance,Payee,NHIF,NSSF,Pension,NetPay) VALUES('" + empNo + "','" + empName + "','" + department + "','" + basicPay + "','" + hseAllowance + "','" + payee + "','" + nhif + "','" + nssf + "','" + pension + "','" + netPay + "')";

            try {

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
                Statement st = con.prepareStatement(query);

                int count = st.executeUpdate(query);
                boolean action = (count > 0);
                if (action) {
                    empnotf.setText(null);
                    empnametf.setText(null);
                    empdpttf.setText(null);
                    basicsaltf.setText(null);
                    hseallowancetf.setText(null);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private class Cancel implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EmployeeRecords3 er = new EmployeeRecords3();
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you can use a `CardLayout` - Tutorial: [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you made is that you create a new JTable **every time you open the viewpanel**. You not only create a new one, **you add it to your view-JPanel**. This is why you get the weird behaviour.

This code snippet fixes your problem. I just added the `removeAll()` method call to the add-JPanel ActionListener. When the add-JPanel is opened, the old JTable is removed from the view-JPanel. I had to comment out your database interactions.

```
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            if (viewpanel.isShowing())
            {
                remove(viewpanel);
                /*
                 * I basically just added this one line.
                 * Since you want to make a fresh query after
                 * you come back to the viewpanel, we can delete
                 * all the elements (which is only the JTable).
                 */
                viewpanel.removeAll();
                add(addpanel);
            }

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    });

    view.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            java.util.List<String[]> datalist = new ArrayList<>();

            String[] columnNames = {"Emp ID", "Emp Name", "Department",
                    "Basic Pay", "House Allowance", "Payee", "NHIF", "NSSF",
                    "Pension", "NetPay"};
            try
            {
                //                    String query = "SELECT * FROM payroll";
                //                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                //                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username,
                //                            password);
                //                    Statement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
                //                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                String[] results = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
                        "i", "j"};
                datalist.add(results);
                //                    con.close();
                String[][] data = new String[datalist.size()][];
                data = datalist.toArray(data);
                JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
                viewpanel.add(sp);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (addpanel.isShowing())
            {
                remove(addpanel);
                add(viewpanel);
            }
            else if (viewpanel.isShowing())
            {
                remove(viewpanel);
                add(viewpanel);
            }

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    });
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
```

The solution on top is not the only one of course. I don't know where you wanna go with this UI, but you can just **remove the contents of the table and refill them as soon as you open the view-JPanel again**.

Another solution would be **to remove the JTable specifically** (but in this case you probably need to have it as a field, because you create the table in a block that you can't reference from your `add.addActionListener`-Block)

The third solution would be to add a **boolean flag, that checks if the table has been loaded and only create a new JTable, if it hasn't**.